# Default for optional string option in .ado program

Tags: stata

I wrote a .ado program that generates a new variable. I would like to have a 
default suffix appended to the new variable, but allow a user-specified 
suffix. That is, by default append `_tr` to the original variable's name, but 
allow a user-specified suffix, say `_tr1pct`.

Is this possible with `syntax`?

My `syntax` line is as follows.

```
syntax varlist [if] [in] ///
    [, Byvar(varlist) Tail(real 1) ///
    Suffix(string) noRelabel]
```

And the suffix is applied later in the program as follows.

```
clonevar `x'_`suffix' = `x' ///
    if `thisuse' & inrange(`pct', `tail', 100 - `tail')
```

I tried `Suffix(string tr)` and `Suffix(string "tr")`, but these are syntax 
errors. I guess I can't have a default argument to an option (and I can't find 
anything about defaults for string options, in any case).

Is there a way to give local macro `suffix` a default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can declare `Suffix(string)` as an option and then after `syntax` go

```
if "`suffix'" == "" local suffix "_tr"
```

If the user didn't specify an argument, the local macro `suffix` will be empty and you define what it should be. That's a default.

I don't know a reason why `syntax` does not allow this, but I take this to be the standard procedure given that it does not.